# How to send and receive data (and / or data structures) from a C ++ script to a Python script?

Tags: python, c++

I am working on a project that needs to do the following:

1. [C++ Program] Checks a given directory, extracts all the names (full paths) of the found files and records them in a `vector<string>`.
2. [C++ Program] "Send" the vector to a Python script.
3. [Python Script] "Receive" the vector and transform it into a `List`.
4. [Python Script] Compares the elements of the List (the paths) against the records of a database and removes the matches from the List (removes the paths already registered).
5. [Python Script] "Sends" the processed List back to the C++ Program.
6. [C++ Program] "Receives" the List, transforms it into a vector and continues its operations with this processed data.

**I would like to know how to send and receive data structures (or data) between a C ++ Script and a Python Script.**

For this case I put the example of a vector transforming into a List, however I would like to know how to do it for any structure or data in general.

Obviously I am a beginner, that is why I would like your help on **what documentation to read, what concepts should I start with, what technique should I use (maybe there is some implicit standard), what links I could review to learn how to communicate data between Scripts of the languages ​​I just mentioned**.

Any help is useful to me.

Comment: will you start the python script from the c++ program or is the python script up and running and waiting for input ?

Comment: Are you doing some interfacing thing?

Comment: @SamDaniel The python script code would have the "sys" library imported and the processing would be done with the arguments received from C++, so it would be waiting for C++ to execute and send data to do its processing.

Comment: @Pygirl I am new to this topic, I know that the data sent can be a simple string with JSON format, and that way it would handle the interface, however I don't know how to send this data from one script to another.

Comment: @JulioZaravia So you would start the python program from c++ :) is what I understand.. easiest way is to use files as medium of communication.

Comment: @SamDaniel So you mean that the C ++ program writes a file with the data and the Python script listens for modifications to this file to read the data, modify it and overwrite it? I had thought about that but wanted the solution to be "more direct" between the two scripts.

I mean, I thought that I could generate a string with a specific format like JSON, and from C ++ execute the script in Python passing this string as an argument.

Comment: Seems maybe unnecessarily complicated. If you are able to write 4) surely you can write the one line of Python needed to do 1) which means you don't need to do 2) or 3)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to any process/script no matter what language they are written in.

In C++ they are represented as `argc` (number of arguments) and `argv` (actual arguments).

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Have " << argc << " arguments:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

For example, if you're using g++ as your compiler. Then running:

```
g++ file.cpp -o main
./main hello world
```

Should output:

```
Have 3 arguments:
hello
world
```

Note that size of the arguments is 3 although you're passing `hello` and `world` only, it's because the first element in `argv` is always the name of your program.

Its equivalent in Python would be:

```
import sys 
print('Have ' + len(sys.argv) + 'arguments:') 
print("Argument List:", str(sys.argv))
```

If I were you, I would start by serializing the vector/list and pass it as an argument back and forth between the Python and C++ processes as above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your two examples you explain how to read and use the arguments, but my question is how to send them from one script to another without writing it manually on the command line. For example, in my case the C ++ script automatically checks the directory every hour and automatically creates the vector and sends it to the Python script, who processes it and returns it to the C ++ program again, in all these activities there will not be a person who can enter the arguments manually.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I misunderstood the "send" and "receive" bits. :)

Comment: Regarding your comment about "serializing" the data, I know that what is sent can be formatted using JSON, which would ultimately be a string, my problem is that I still don't know how to send this string from one script to another. I understand that received the "string" I can parse it in multiple ways, however I don't know how to send it. I'm currently reading about the use of the "Python.h" library which seems to solve my question, although I still do not understand its use very well.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but you can pass arguments from one "script" to another by calling `system()` with the desired command-line arguments in your code, like `system("g++ file.cpp -o main")` and capturing its output to do what you want with it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out redis. It can be used as a message broker between programs. https://redis.io/

They have a clients for many langues including c++ and python.
https://redis.io/clients

You can set up channels for each program to publish messages through and have the other program subscribe to that channel to receive those messages.
Check out the pubsub part of the documentation: https://redis.io/topics/pubsub

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is to execute the python script from the c++ process, then the easiest would be to design the python script to accept `input_file` and `output_file` as arguments and the c++ program should write the `input_file`, start the script and read the `output_file`.

For simple structures like list-of-strings, you can simply write them as text files and share, but for more complex types, you can use google-protocolbuffers to do the marshalling/unmarshalling.

if the idea is to send/receive data between two already stared process, then you can use the same protocol buffers to encode data and send/receive via sockets between each other. Check `gRPC`